# double top 10 ranking of user with most procedures and the type of the procedures with most occurrences within a user

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

i have a column with the ids of doctors and another column with the procedure type

assuming all the elements are filled in, how could i do a top 10 ranking of which doctor did the most procedures where the id of the doctor is followed by which procedure he realized the most?

I was thinking the following:

```
select a.doctor, count(a.doctor) as num_procedures, x.type as most_frequent_procedure from schedule as a left join (select doctor, type, count(type) from schedule group by type, doctor) as x on a.doctor = x.doctor group by a.doctor order by num_procedures desc limit 10;
```

but it is not giving me the desired result and i cant help but think i am over-complicating things with this query.

Any help is greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `max(count)` of procedure types before joining to doctors per #of procedures.

```
select a.doctor, count(1) as num_procedures, b.type
from schedule a
left join
    (select max(t.ct), t.doctor, t.type from
        (select doctor, type, count(1) ct
            from schedule group by doctor, type) t group by t.doctor, t.type) b on b.doctor = a.doctor
group by a.doctor
limit 10;
```